# Pandas reindex and fill missing values: "Index must be monotonic"

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

In answering [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981678/how-to-align-indexes-of-many-dataframes-and-fill-in-respective-missing-values-in), I found some interesting behavior when using a fill method while reindexing a dataframe.

This [old bug report](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5669) in pandas says that `df.reindex(newIndex,method='ffill')` should be equivalent to `df.reindex(newIndex).ffill()`, but that is NOT the behavior I'm witnessing

Here's a code snippet that illustrates the behavior

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': 2}, index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-06-02', '2016-05-04', '2016-06-03']))
newIndex = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-04', '2016-06-01', '2016-06-02', '2016-06-03', '2016-06-05'])
print(df.reindex(newIndex).ffill())
print(df.reindex(newIndex, method='ffill'))
```

The first print statement works as expected. The second raises a

```
ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
```

What's going on here?

---

EDIT: Note that the sample `df` *intentionally* has a non-monotonic index. The question pertains to the order of operations in `df.reindex(newIndex, method='ffil')`. My expectation is as the bug-report says it should work- first reindex with the new index and then fill.

As you can see, the `newIndex.is_monotonic` is `True`, and the fill works when called separately but fails when called as a parameter to `reindex`.

Answer (score 3):

Some element of `reindex` requires the incoming index to be sorted.  I'm deducing that when `method` is passed, it fails to presort the incoming index and subsequently fails.  I'm drawing this conclusion based on the fact that this works:

```
print df.sort_index().reindex(newIndex.sort_values(), method='ffill')
```

Comment: This is indeed the issue the stack trace:`1940         indexer = self.get_indexer(target)
   1941         nonexact = (indexer == -1)
-> 1942         indexer[nonexact] = self._searchsorted_monotonic(target[nonexact], side)
   1943         if side == 'left':
   1944             # searchsorted returns "indices into a sorted array such that,
` shows that the index must be sorted in order for this to work, this makes sense as you can't `ffill` if the index isn't sorted

Comment: @piRSquared it was late when I wrote this question last night. note that `all(newIndex.sort_values()==newIndex)` is `True`. The piece of your snippet that makes it work is the df.sort_index()` call. My example `df` intentionally has a non-monotonic index. My expectation of how `reindex(newIndex, method='ffill')` would be to FIRST reindex and then fill, and not the other way around.

Comment: @EdChum, I agree `ffill` on a non-monotonic index doesn't make sense. But my `newIndex` IS monotonic. My expectation on `df.reindex(newIndex, method='ffill')` would be to first reindex with `newIndex` and then fill. But that is clearly not what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this needs to be done on the columns as well.

```
In[76]: frame = DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), index=['a', 'c', 'd'],columns=['Ohio', 'Texas', 'California'])

In[77]: frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'],method='ffill',columns=states)
---> ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

In[78]: frame.reindex(index=['a','b','c','d'],method='ffill',columns=states.sort())

Out[78]:
  Ohio  Texas  California
a     0      1           2
b     0      1           2
c     3      4           5
d     6      7           8
```

Comment: This issue is caused by column is not sorted. Therefore, I think this answer is more accurate.